# Google cardboard error in android studio. Cannot run build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cardboard

As I described above, I am having trouble getting the Google Cardboard sample code to open properly, and it seems to be a build error. Android studio, the android sdk, JDK are all recently updated. I am still able to create and open other android projects. I downloaded the sample code from github, exactly following the instructions on the google cardboard webpage.

The full error message is

`Cannot run program "C:\GitHub\cardboard-java\build.gradle" (in directory "C:\GitHub\cardboard-java"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application: Cannot run program "C:\GitHub\cardboard-java\build.gradle" (in directory "C:\GitHub\cardboard-java"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

The instructions I've bee following can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started), and I could not get past the first step in the "Build the app demo" section. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Tools>Android>Synch Project With Gradle Files. This might give you a bit more info.